# Brownian motion probability P(B2>B1>B3)

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

For standard Brownian motion, I'm trying to  find $P(B_2>B_1>B_3)$, which I thought  I could split into:

$=P(B_2>B_1)*P(B_1>B_3)$
$=P(B_2-B_1>0)*P(B_1-B_3>0)$
$=(1-P(B_2-B_1\leq0))*(1-P(B_1-B_3\leq0))$

which in R I calculated using:

```
 (1-pnorm(0,0,1))*(1-pnorm(0,0,sqrt(2)))
```

But I'm  not sure if this is  the right answer! Is what I'm doing sound?

Comment: The events $\{B_2 > B_1\}$ and $\{B_1 > B_3\}$ are not independent, so you cannot do what you did in your first step.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, in that case, what's the correct calculation?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$Z_1= B_2-B_1$ and $Z_2= B_3-B_2$ are independent $N(0,1)$ and your event is equivalent to $\{Z_1>0,Z_2+Z_1<0\}.$ (And no, you can’t split this up by independence either, but it’s a pretty easy to understand region of $Z_1-Z_2$ space.)